# open file on server for local editing using php

Tags: php, file

I have a collection of documents and assorted goodies on a server. These files are managed through use of a simple php based web app. As the system stands, if anybody wants to edit a file they need to download it, make their changes and upload it again. I would like to make the files effectively editable online. My idea is that when a user clicks on an 'edit' button associated with a file, that file will be copied to a secure location on the server that the user has access to. That's the easy bit. What I would like to know is how to get the client's pc to launch the appropriate application for editing the document (such as excel or whatever). Any ideas?

You know when you download a file and it shows up in your little downloads box in your browser? If you click-click on that file then the browser causes the host computer to open it up. I'm wondering if there is a way to achieve something similar sans click-click. I dont want to just make things run on the user's pc, I want to ask the user's os nicely to open a file from a specific location for editing. The click-click method of opening files from a browser download window as far as i know is accepted as an ok thing to do. I want to emulate that.

Comment: In summary, you want your web application to launch an application on the client computer which will edit a file located on some server? I do not think that is possible, and I sure hope I am not wrong. I my browser can launch an application without my OK, I think I will uninstall it in a heartbeat.

Comment: Specifically with IE and MSO documents, if the server supports the PUT method for the request URI, you can edit the document locally and when you press "Save" it saves it back to the server. In order to implement this, the following conditions must be true: The user must be using IE6+, the server must support HTTP PUT for the exact URI requested to obtain the document, and the server must report this in response to an OPTIONS request, and the document must be a Microsoft Office document format.

Answer (score 1):

What do you refer to with "secure location on the server that the user has access to"? If this is accessed via FTP, a Samba share, WebDAV or something similar the user will have to open the file himself.

In general I would say there is no solution to what you want. There is no way to have a kind of "online" editing. You need to go through the download/upload sequence unless you code a complex JavaScript application that is capable of dealing with real "online editing" (see Google Docs etc.)